# Making an event in one hour without using a timer (UserDefaults)

Tags: ios, swift, userdefaults

I'm having an issue of concepts I guess with some part of an iOS app I'm trying to make. Basically, in this app you add an item to a list, and this item expires in 1 hour. So you have one hour to use it. However, I want this to continue in case the app crashes or if the user exits. So I can't use a `Timer()` (Or can I?).
 I'm thinking the easiest way is to use `UserDefaults` and save a key called **dateExp** or something, and have that date be **.now() + 3600** or something (I don't know exactly how to set that). and then on viewdidload check that key and compare it to current `.now()` and if it's past its time then it should auto-delete it from the list.
I am however at a loss of what tools to even use (other than `UserDefaults`). the delete / add methods are fairly simple, the only thing I'm having issues is with the continuing timer even when the app closes.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Local notifications.

[Scheduling Local Notifications for delivery](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/SchedulingandHandlingLocalNotifications.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH5-SW5)

This code is directly from Apple's documentation

```
let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
content.title = NSString.localizedUserNotificationString(forKey: "Wake up!", arguments: nil)
content.body = NSString.localizedUserNotificationString(forKey: "Rise and shine! It's morning time!",
                                                        arguments: nil)

// Configure the trigger for a 7am wakeup.
var dateInfo = DateComponents()
dateInfo.hour = 7
dateInfo.minute = 0
let trigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: dateInfo, repeats: false)

// Create the request object.
let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: "MorningAlarm", content: content, trigger: trigger)
```

Then, if you want your application to do something when the notification comes when your app is in the foreground

[Handling Notifications When Your App Is in the Foreground](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/SchedulingandHandlingLocalNotifications.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH5-SW15)

This is an example of implementing the delegate 
also from Apple docs:

```
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                            willPresent notification: UNNotification,
                            withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
    // Update the app interface directly.

    // Play a sound.
    completionHandler(UNNotificationPresentationOptions.sound)
}
```

From Apple docs

> If you want the system to continue to display the notification interface, provide a delegate object for the UNUserNotificationCenter and implement the userNotificationCenter:willPresentNotification:withCompletionHandler: method. Your implementation of this method should still process the notification data. When finished, execute the provided completion handler block with the delivery option (if any) that you want the system to use. If you do not specify any options, the system silences the notification. Listing 3-4 shows a sample implementation of this method that tells the system to play a sound. The notification’s payload identifies which sound to play.

Comment: Thank you for that suggestion. Is there an import or something thats needed to enable this? even a copy paste from apple's sample code says UNMutableNoficiationContent() is an unresolved identifier. Does this need push notifications or whats the deal?

Comment: From what I'm reading this does require user permission, I don't think it would be the best approach as I would have to assume everyone will grant permission to the app to do push notifications. I want this to be available regardless of those permissions.

Comment: `import UserNotifications` , `import UserNotificationsUI`. Thanks for notifying

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is indeed to manage the expiration timestamps in your lists's data structure and store them in userDefaults.

You simply need a timer to periodically (e.g. once per second) go through the list and remove expired entries.